# Passing variable into shell function in string

Tags: shell

I think I've tried every possible combination at this point.

I want to call my function with a passed argument which should be inputted into the curl url.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
foo () {    
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"requestKeys":["$1"]}' -X POST https://www.url.com/    
}    
foo $1
```

I am calling this function from bash like this

```
./test.sh "myInput"
```

The result of the curl url should be exactly as follows ( including the quote marks etc )

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"requestKeys":["myInput"]}' -X POST https://www.url.com/
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I am getting "Base64URL decode failed: invalid base64 encoding near offset" error.

I believe it must be an issue with how I am variably inputting $1 into the curl requestKeys.

I believe my syntax is wrong.

Could anyone please enlighten me how should the syntax look like?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `'...'` strings in POSIX-compatible shells do not perform string interpolation - use `"..."` strings instead, and escape the embedded `"` as ``\"``.

Comment: @mklement0 I tried ``` curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"requestKeys":["$1"]}" -X POST url.com ``` and it still doesn't work. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, that's not what was meant. `"{\"requestKeys\":[\"$1\"]}"` -- mind, it's a _bad_ solution, but it's good enough for the string `myInput`. If you want something that works for _any_ string, you should be using `jq` (ignore any answer you find on SO that _doesn't_ use `jq --arg`)

Comment: Also, `foo $1` should be `foo "$1"`

Comment: ...but other than those missing quotes, the passing-into-a-function part is not what you got wrong.